# What to do if not all theoretically related variables are loaded highly on the same factors using EFA?

Tags: regression, factor-analysis

I'm using EFA to generate regression factor scores for subsequent regression and ANOVA analyses. I want to do use regression factor scores instead of averaging the scores, as I've read in multiple sources (for example; DiStefano et al., 2009) this is the better way.

For this analysis I got 13 variables, which theoretically represent four constructs. When I run EFA (in SPSS) however, only three factors are created when following the eigenvalue>1 rule. Consequently, some variables are combined which theoretically are different ones. If I give SPSS the notion that I want four factors, there is still some mixing of certain variables. Which I guess is due to measurement error. I've read (Black et al., 2014 p126) that it's okay if it's slightly lower but some are (even after rotation) mixed.

Now I'm wondering if it is (still) allowed to seperately run factor analyses for each contruct. My main purpuse being to (summarize) the scores of the variables into one main variable (so four variables, one for each contruct). Even without this mixing it is still a mystery for me if for this purpose the EFA should be run multiple times for each construct once to create regression factor scores (so you know which one is which and the correct factor is used to represent the correct factor), or all in once. For this I have to note that I'm aware of the following as stated by Black et al. (2014; p130) "*The one key characteristic that differentiates a factor score from a summated scale is that the factor score is computed based on the factor loadings of all variables on the factor, whereas the summated scale is calculated by combining only selected variables.*"

On a side note: Two of these variables are DV and IV, and two are only IV. and I'm thinking of using Barlett's method to save the regression factor scores.

So basically, these are the questions:

- In order to create regression factor scores, does for each construct (if theoretically known) need seperate EFA's (in spss) be run?
- What to do if variables from the same theoretical construct load on different factors?

References:

- Hair, Black, Babin and Anderson (2014) Multivariate Data Analysis. 7th Edition. Pearson New International Edition (ISBN 13: 978-1-292-02190-4)
- DiStefano, Christine, Zhu, Min & Mîndrilă, Diana (2009). Understanding and Using Factor Scores: Considerations for the Applied Researcher. Practical Assessment, Research & Evaluation, 14 (20).

Comment: Q2. Try maybe oblique rotation. If it doesn't help that simply means those items loaded by different factors correlate too poorly, and so your construct is a battery, ie not correlation-based. Note also that 13 items is a bit few for EFA expecting 4 factors, in real settings. Get more items. Q1. If FA of 13 items does not support your constructs as factors computing factor scores is meaningless. Of course, you can run 4 separate analysis, one for each construct, extracting 1 factor and saving scores, but if correlations are weak the exercise is of little utility.

Comment: EFA is really good and helpful when you have many items (much more then factors to extract). Typically, 20-100 items (and sample size 5 times to that) which cover well the whole field of the correlating phenomena in your domain of interest. Then Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin MSE will be high.

Comment: I've tried oblique rotation but that doesn't make the factors load better unfortunately. The main relationships I'm testing do come out with the same conclusion when I average the scores and when I use factor scores (calculated using Barletts method, principal axis factoring and no rotation). Although the p-values and the standard error of the estimate both are lower. Given your previous comment @ttnphns, I'm wondering if these differences say anything or are just meaningless.

Comment: If you expect that each your construct is based on latent factor, why not do CFA instead of EFA?

Comment: @ttnphns I haven't really thought about it yet since my main purpose is to test some hypotheses such as if someone's attitude towards a website has a significant impact on net promotor score and purchase probability. For this I intend to use linear regression for which I need the regression factor scores. But it's a good suggestion to add to my master thesis research (thanks for that) as it's now also quite important to find out how well the measured variables represent the constructs.